# DRF/Angular: form data with nested objects with dotted/[] notation

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, form-data

I'm sending form data to Django Rest Framework View like this for all serialized data of a nested object named security:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAOygB8mq3Oo5I7ii
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="security[title]"

P
```

and it fails with 400 error saying that the field `security` is required.

When I'm using the DRF's web view and fill the form there, POST it I'm seeing that the notation is like this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAOygB8mq3Oo5I7ii
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="security.title"

P
```

As I'm using angular with `ng-upload` and its Upload lib (coffee):

```
    Upload.upload(
      url: '/services/rest/.../'+id+'/upload'
      data:
        $scope.object)
```

to send the form data.

Question which is correct? the dotted or [] notation? Which side to fix?

Answer (score 2):

found it: Upload lib can be configured by `objectKey: '.k'`

details:

  `*data: {key: file, otherInfo: uploadInfo},
  /*
  This is to accommodate server implementations expecting nested data object keys in .key or [key] format.
  Example: data: {rec: {name: 'N', pic: file}} sent as: rec[name] -> N, rec[pic] -> file

     data: {rec: {name: 'N', pic: file}, objectKey: '.k'} sent as: rec.name -> N, rec.pic -> file */

  objectKey: '[k]' or '.k' // default is '[k]'`

Answer (score 1):

You Should try make your key as `security.title` in FormData

Comment: From Review: This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve your explanation, or just post it as a comment to the question.